# Error "-fabi-version=2" when installing Msyqldb or Flask-mysqldb (or any mysql client) in PyCharm on Mac OS using AMPPS

Tags: python, mysql, pycharm

I'm a beginner Python programmer and currently using pyCharm CE IDE on a MAC OS High Sierra system following a tutorial to create a database web-app.

The issue I am facing is when I try to add any mysql access library in 'requirements.txt' the installation fails. (tried with Flask-Mysqldb, mysqlclient, mysqldb)

I figured out that the issue i was facing earlier `missing mysql_config` was due to using AMPPS (Softaculous) MAMP stack and was able to fix it by updating my $PATH  variable to include the path to `/Applications/AMPPS/mysql/bin`

Now the error I am getting is

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-fabi-version=2'
```

Most of the solutions I have come across are suggestions to replace MAMP MySQL with the homebrew version (or something similar). Ideally I would like to stick with AMPPS since I am familiar with this and have other apps currently hosted on it (e.g. Wordpress).

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue by following the below steps:

1. modify `mysql_config` at `/Applications/AMPPS/mysql/bin`
2. Remove '-fabi-version=2' flag from 'cflags' (around line:122)
3. successfully install mysqlclient (or MySQLdb)